# Not able to store the response in the message store

Tags: logging, wso2, esb

Need to sent the request(URl, header, payload) and response logs to the rest api. We are using the Message store and Message processor using the WSO2 Message Broker. Below is the api we are configured.

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="plants-logging" context="/plants-logging">
<resource methods="POST GET DELETE PUT">
  <inSequence>
     <log level="custom">
        <property name="HTTP_METHOD IS###########" expression="$axis2:HTTP_METHOD"></property>
        <property name="ip address" expression="get-property('axis2','REMOTE_ADDR')"></property>
        <property name="In Time : " expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')"></property>
     </log>
     <property name="TIME_IN" expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')" scope="default" type="LONG"></property>
     <log level="custom">
        <property name="Message Flow" value="ACCEPTED@"></property>
     </log>
     <send>
        <endpoint>
           <address uri="/test/api/"></address>
        </endpoint>
     </send>
     <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"></property>
     <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" action="remove"></property>
     <switch source="$axis2:HTTP_METHOD">
        <case regex="POST">
           <store messageStore="JMSMS"></store>
        </case>
        <case regex="PUT">
           <store messageStore="JMSMS"></store>
        </case>
     </switch>
     <property name="TIME_OUT" expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')" scope="default" type="LONG"></property>
     <script language="js">var time1 = mc.getProperty("TIME_IN");var time2 = mc.getProperty("TIME_OUT");var timeTaken = time2 - time1;mc.setProperty("RESPONSE_TIME", timeTaken);</script>
     <log level="custom">
        <property name="Time Duration in ms:" expression="get-property('RESPONSE_TIME') "></property>
     </log>
  </inSequence>
  <outSequence>
     <log level="custom">
        <property name="Out Sequence" value="ACCEPTED@"></property>
     </log>
     <switch source="$axis2:HTTP_METHOD">
        <case regex="GET">
            <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"></property>
            <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" action="remove"></property>
            <store messageStore="JMSMS"></store>
        </case>
     </switch>
  </outSequence>
  <faultSequence>
     <log level="custom">
        <property name="Fault Sequence" value="ACCEPTED@"></property>
     </log>
     <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"></property>
     <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" action="remove"></property>
     <store messageStore="JMSMS"></store>
  </faultSequence>
</resource>
</api>
```

For POST request the payload is able to send to our rest api successfullly. But for the response we are getting.

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Payload could not be written as JSON.
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.writeAsJson(JsonUtil.java:109)
    at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter.writeTo(JsonStreamFormatter.java:60)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRequestEntity.writeRequest(AxisRequestEntity.java:84)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:499)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:622)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:193)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:451)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:278)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.sendReceive(BlockingMsgSender.java:217)
    at org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.send(BlockingMsgSender.java:146)
    at org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ForwardingService.dispatch(ForwardingService.java:288)
    at org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ForwardingService.execute(ForwardingService.java:128)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
```

[2014-11-28 18:27:33,615] ERROR - ForwardingService BlockingMessageSender of message processor [SMFP] failed to send message to the endpoint
[2014-11-28 18:27:33,615]  WARN - ForwardingService Failed to send the message through the fault sequence, Sequence name null does not Exist.
[2014-11-28 18:27:37,634] ERROR - JsonUtil #writeAsJson. Payload could not be written as JSON. MessageID: urn:uuid:20310054-7f03-4e7e-853e-9bc98f27a063
[2014-11-28 18:27:37,634] ERROR - JsonUtil #writeAsJson. Payload could not be written as JSON. MessageID: urn:uuid:20310054-7f03-4e7e-853e-9bc98f27a063

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?